# Dimension of rows space and columns space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The rank of the below matrix confused me. Since it has $3$ independent rows, so the dimension of rows space should be $3$. However, it also has $7$ independent columns, then the dimension of columns space is $7$ also?

\begin{pmatrix}
1& -2& 0& 19& -6& 0& -37\\
0& 0& 1& -6& 2& 0& 6\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 3\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dimension of a matrix" makes no sense.  Dimension is a property of vector spaces, not of individual vectors or matrices.

Your matrix has three independent rows (and no more), so the dimension of its **row space** is $3$.

If a matrix has seven independent columns (in fact, yours doesn't) and no more, then the dimension of its **column space** will be $7$.

Answer (score 1):

It actually doesn't have $7$ independent columns (for example the second column is $-2$ times the first)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned David Sir, ""Dimension of a matrix" makes no sense"-it is true fact. I think it may be "Rank of a matrix".  However in detailed solution of the problem we see that only $1st$ $3rd$ and $6th$ columns are linearly independent, remaining all rows can be expressed as a linear combinations of these three columns. So $dim (\text{column space})=3$. Also $dim (\text{row space})=3$, since it has three independent rows also. Moreover for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$

> $$dim (\text{row space of A})=dim (\text{column space of A})= rank(A).$$